# VBA Search a worksheet for Textbox1, if TB1 is found check if TB2 text is adjacent

Tags: vba, excel

I am updating this in case anyone else out there may have a need for it and to see if anyone has any suggestions to this code (I am very new to VBA so any critiques are welcome).

The following code will search Column 2 of a giving worksheet for the textBox1 value. If not found it will add the information. If it is found, it finds all instances of said find and searches the adjacent column for Textbox 2. If not found it adds the information, if it is found it returns a Msgbox.

```
`Private Sub cbAdd_Click()
Dim wss As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long
Dim Fnd As String, FF As String, Change As String
Dim FC As Range, LC As Range, Rng As Range, ChgId As Range
Dim FndChg As Range, SRange As Range, Rng2 As Range

'tb = Text Box, cb = Combo Box
'These are the values that need to be found, if present.
mis = tbMis.Text
Change = tbChg.Text

'Activate the Sheet to search in, then set the search criteria.

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DB").Activate
Set wss = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DB") 'wss for me is worksheet searched
Set SRange = wss.Columns(2) 'Sets the range to search with SRange as Column  B of "DB"
Set LC = SRange.Cells(SRange.Cells.count) 'Finds the LastCell (LC) of the  search range
Set FC = SRange.Find(what:=mis, after:=LC) 'FC is the First Cell found matching "mis"
LR = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Finds the last row in the "DB"   worksheet, used when adding the information.

'Checking to see if anything was found.
If FC Is Nothing Then
    GoTo AddMis 'If the mis is not found, add the information.
End If

If Not FC Is Nothing Then 'If mis was found FF (First Found) is the address  of where it was found.
    FF = FC.Address
End If

Set Rng = FC

'This loops the search until it finds all instances of mis in column 2.
Do Until FC Is Nothing
Set FC = SRange.FindNext(after:=FC) 'Continues the search after the last    found cell.
Set Rng = Union(Rng, FC) 'Adds the found cells to my range "Rng".
If FC.Address = FF Then Exit Do 'continues the loop until it cycles to the  first found cell.
Loop

Rng.Select
Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select 'Selects adjacent cells in order to see if these match "change".
Set ChgId = Selection.Find(what:=Change, Lookat:=True) 'Will compare Column 3 against info input into "change"

If Not ChgId Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Duplicate
Else
    GoTo AddMis
End If

'Handlers
AddMis:
Sheets("DB").Range("A" & LR + 1).Value = tbSat.Text 'Adds the ComboBox1  selection to the next available row in column 1.
Sheets("DB").Range("A" & LR + 1).Offset(0, 1).Value = tbMis.Text 'Adds tbMis  Text to the same row in column 2.
Sheets("DB").Range("A" & LR + 1).Offset(0, 2).Value = tbChg.Text 'Adds tbChg Text to the same row in column 3.
Sheets("DB").Range("A" & LR + 1).Offset(0, 3).Value = tbPri.Text 'Adds ComboBox2 selection to the same row in column 4.

Msgbox "Information added" 'Lets the user know the information has been added.
Unload Me 'Closes the Userform with the input fields
Exit Sub
Duplicate:
Msgbox "Information has already been input into the database." 'Lets the   user know that the information already exists.
Unload Me
Exit Sub

End Sub'
```

I would like to thank the entire overflow community, although there may not have been a definitive answer on this question, the site and knowledge base of others available helped me ultimately solve this problem.

Comment: if you are getting all these options from an Excel sheet, you don't need VBA, you can just use Data --> Remove Duplicates

Comment: is `Findstring ` to be searched in column "A" only and then, if found, check for adjacent cell in column B against `Findchange `? Do you have to check for ALL matching values in column "A". Please add a "before" and "after" scenario

Comment: @ShaiRado I need to keep all previous entries in the worksheet and add new ones if Column A and B dont match TB1 and TB2 values.

Comment: @user3598756 yes, and yes. If Column A has no match, find the next available row and add the info. If column A has at least one match I need to check the matches in their adjacent cell (column B) against 'findchange'   if "Findstring" is in Col A with 'Findchange' adjacent in Col B, return msgbox, if not add the info.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.Offset` property to access cells relative to a certain cell:

```
'...
If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
    If Rng.Offset(0,1).Value = Findchange Then
        MsgBox "Item already entered." 
    End If
Else
'...
```

You can't do both checks within one line (`Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Offset(0,1).Value = Findchange`) because VBA will check the second condition even if the first isn't true.

You can also search column 1 instead of the whole sheet:

```
Set Rng = ws.Columns(1).Find('...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have implemented your suggestions, but now I am having the issue of it will always add the information.

Comment: In your example the items are in column 1 but you are looking in column two...?

Comment: I need to find column 2 value first, to see  if it matches the TB1. if it matches I need to see if TB2 matches the adjacent value. if not add the TB values to the next available row.

Comment: sorry that's correct, the data to match is in column 2 not 1.

Comment: Try stepping through your code using F8 to see why it's adding unwanted items. There is a guide to debugging in the [vba] tag-wiki I think l. I'm on mobile so can't really help you any more...